# Stop function from being executed after run once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a **this function**

```
function toDiv() {
$(".wrap"))) 

    $('.barfill').each(function(){
        var width=$(this).data('width');
        $(this).animate({ width: width }, 500);
        var $perctext = $('<div>', {'class': 'perctext', text: width});
        $perctext.appendTo(this);
        $perctext.delay(500).each(function(a) {
            $(this).delay(a * 250).animate({
            'left': width
        }, 1000);
    });
}); 
else {}
}
```

**that runs after the element appears on the pane by using this.**

```
function toView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

I want it to **run ONCE** and when the element is on the pane again the function won't trigger  again.

I applied **.one()** to the parent function so it runs only once but that **didn't do the trick**.

You can check the [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/helionbc/EzqLd/5/) to clarify the problem further.

**Note:** I updated this question for clarity, since it seemed to create some misunderstandings.

Comment: You seem to have been downvoted for a perfectly acceptable question.  Upvoted to counter.

Comment: @HélioC The counter principle, I think, it should be more simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) to remove the listener once it's been used:

```
$(window).scroll(toDiv);

function toView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

function toDiv() {

    if (toView(
    $(".wrap"))) {
        $('.barfill').each(function () {
            var width = $(this).data('width');
            $(this).animate({
                width: width
            }, 500);
            var $perctext = $('<div>', {
                'class': 'perctext',
                text: width
            });
            $perctext.appendTo(this);
            $perctext.delay(500).each(function (a) {
                $(this).delay(a * 250).animate({
                    'left': width
                }, 1000);
            });
        });
      $(window).unbind('scroll');
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EzqLd/8/)

Comment: Accepted and upvoted. Quick question: unbind is a better practice over creating the flag to check if it was executed?  Or is simply the short/cleaner way to achieve it?

Comment: @HélioC Unbind is better practice, I just had a brain fart.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

```
function highlander(fn) {
  return function() [
    if (fn) {
      fn.apply(this, arguments);
      fn = null;
    }
  }
}

var printHello = highlander(function() {
  console.log('Hello');
});

printHello();
printHello();
printHello();
// will print hello only once!
```

Comment: This isn't any more useful than `.one()` which the OP has already said they don't want.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks. The original question wasn't very clear on this. The update did actual make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should be found, simply, in the original counter principle.

```
// define a counter
var counter = 0;
$(window).scroll(toDiv);
function toView(elem) {
    //check the counter value
    if (counter > 0) return false;      
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();    
    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));

}
function toDiv() {
    if (toView(
        $(".wrap"))) 

        $('.barfill').each(function(){
            // increase the counter value
            counter++;
            var width=$(this).data('width');
            $(this).animate({ width: width }, 500);
            var $perctext = $('<div>', {'class': 'perctext', text: width});
            $perctext.appendTo(this);
            $perctext.delay(500).each(function(a) {
                $(this).delay(a * 250).animate({
                    'left': width
                }, 1000);
            });
        });

    else {

         }

}
```

Checkout the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EzqLd/9/)